# Make sure signed message can't be reused over IRC chat

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

I want to send "administrative messages" over an IRC chat. So for instance, I want to be able to give points to a person during an animation and everyone can see it in their UI because I can change their web client.

Given I sign a message with an RSA key, people can make sure I issued the message the first time. However, I would like to prevent people from reusing my signed message.

Several problems I though of :

- I could simply add a timestamp to the clients but there could be synchronisation errors and the message can be reused if fast enough
- I could cache the messages that I issued so they can't be reused again but people can disconnect and then come back and would have missed the messages, the same problem is true for sequence numbers.
- I could use challenge responses but the network is quite slow and dispatching a message to a handful of clients could slow down my own messages.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This protection only makes sense if you want to prevent a reply attack, if that's not the issue it makes no sense. If you want to protect from a reply attack just use a protocol that uses a session key.

Comment: I think you meant "replay attack", @JonathanAllon

Comment: I do want to prevent against replay attacks but I don't have any session mechanism in place.

Comment: So add a simple client + server side random challenge to the message and sign that.

Comment: Any reason why you are focused on securing the messages as opposed to establishing a secure channel?  How exactly do you anticipate a user will be able to insert a replayed message into the channel?

Comment: For now, it's easy to just copy / paste the signed message onto the IRC channel and other clients will see this is a signed message, then decode it and interpret it as an actual command. How would you create a secure channel ?

Answer (score 1):

There are four major approaches to this sort of problem, which can be combined to get more desirable security properties.

- **Cache the received messages.** In this approach you keep a list (of the hashes) of all received messages. If you find a message in said list, you discard it as a replay. The obvious problem here is the amount of storage needed.
- **Use time-stamps / expiration.** In this approach you add a time-stamp / a time-window or an expiration time to your messages. If they are received outside of the agreed upon window they are discarded. The disadvantage here is that if the attacker is fast enough he can still replay *and* you need to have a relieable clock. This can be effectively combined with the first approach.
- **Use sequence numbers.** In this approach you add a sequence number to your messages. Messages are discarded if their sequence number is lower than the expected value. The obvious disadvantage is that state synchronisation is required.
- **Use challenge-response.** In this approach the client sends an unpredictable challenge to the server, the server includes this challenge in the message and the client keeps the challenge white-listed. As soon as a pending response to an open challenge is received, the message is accepted as valid. As soon as a valid challenge has been accepted the challenge must not longer be considered valid for future use (ie discarded). The obvious disadvantage to this is that the parties are required to be on-line, ie exchange messages somewhat symmetrical and in a timely manner.

For your system, it sounds like the minimal synchronization from the first two approaches offers what you needs.
TLS uses the third approach for the bulk data transport and something like the last for the handshake.

Comment: For option 1, it might be important to make sure each request contains something unique e.g. a UUID.  It's possible that there could be two valid requests that for the same exact action.  For space a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) might work for this as long as it is acceptable for requests to fail due to false positives.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, I updated the main message that was not precise enough, I realized there was an XY problem thanks to the other answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I'm thinking maybe there is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in this question.

This is my guess at your scenario:

1. User's browser attempts to access a restricted application feature
2. Application sends browser to identity web site to get an artifact or bearer token containing the permission necessary to use the restricted feature
3. Identity web site checks user's identity, generates an artifact indicating that the permissions are OK for the operation, signs it, and returns it to the browser
4. Browser accesses the restricted feature, but this time with the token indicating that the user has the necessary permissions.
5. Application reads the token and performs the operation.

In this case, you are concerned that the bearer token, which flows over the internet to the user's browser, could be replaced with a bearer token obtained earlier, for a different user who may have more permissions.

However, you don't want to completely prevent replay.  For example, if step 4 fails due a network problem, the user should be able to refresh the page and try again, and the same token will get submitted again.  This is perfectly OK.

What you do want to prevent is the user submitting a token/artifact from another user. Or if the user's permissions were revoked a day ago, you don't want the user submitting his own token from two days ago.

All you need for this is to ensure

1. The artifact identifies the user
2. The artifact identifiers the permission
3. The artifact states a period over which the permission is granted to the user
4. The artifact is signed in a manner that can be validated

If you do all of the above, there is no need to block replay.  Well, technically item #3 above includes a date range, so that is sort of a weak replay mitigation.  But the idea that each token must be generated in the context of random challenge and response is not correct-- the identity server just needs to state ("assert") that a user, permission, and time window all belong together, and sign it.  Doing so will prevent the sort of attacks I think you're concerned about.

Please correct me if my guesses are incorrect.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I tried to simplify the problem and it was not correct enough, I changed the original message to give more details. Thank you.